# How to set only expanded mode in Today Widget Extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

There are two widget display modes in iOS 10: `NCWidgetDisplayModeCompact` and `NCWidgetDisplayModeExpanded` . The first is enabled by default. How can I enable the default second, but do not show the "show more" / "show less" buttons? In the application "Vidgets" this is implemented.[image]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot hide the `Show less / Show more` button if you set the display mode to expanded.

However, if you set the widget largest available display mode to compact, it should hide it:

```
self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .compact
```

Comment: Yes, that is right. But in this case the height of the widget will always be about 110px. And I need to be able to change it.

Comment: @Developer - Look at the "widgetMaximumSize" on the "extensionContext" for compact mode. You might be able to set the "preferredContentSize" to something larger than what it defaults to, depends on the device model.

Comment: @Ross Barbish - I tried to change the "preferredContentSize" , but for this compact mode it is constant and is about 110pt.

Comment: The compact size is fixed in iOS 10. You could always compile for lower which I guess is how Vidgets is achieving it.